# Firebug giving me a syntax error in OnClick function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

Here's my HTML:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='PatientReady1' value='Yes' checked onClick="PatientReady ("PatientReady1","111","PatientReady")">
```

And my JavaScript:

```
function PatientReady(element, TriageNo, Field){
    debugger;
        if (element.checked == 1){
            new Ajax.Request (
                "PatientReady.asp",
                        {   
                        method: 'post',
                        parameters: {
                                    TriageNo: TriageNo,
                                    strReady: "Yes",
                                    strElement: Field
                                    },
                        asynchronous:false
                            }
                            
                        );
        }
        else{
            new Ajax.Request (
                "PatientReady.asp",
                        {   
                        method: 'post',
                        parameters: {
                                    TriageNo: TriageNo,
                                    strReady: "No",
                                    strElement: Field
                                    },
                        asynchronous:false
                            }
                            
                        );
        }
}
```

For some reason I'm getting a syntax error, when I click on the checkbox... I'm sure I'm missing some tiny stupid thing, perhaps a fresh set of eyes can help?

Comment: onclick="PatientReady ("PatientReady1","111","PatientReady")" - are those supposed to be single quotes in the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark mentioned, if you have double quotes around your string, inside the string should only be single-quotes. It doesn't matter which one you use, but try to be consistent, for readability purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Use apostrophe instead of quotation mark after onClick:

```
onClick="PatientReady('PatientReady1','111','PatientReady')"
```

Also checked should be:

```
checked="checked"
```

Comment: Just `checked` is fine and legal in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='PatientReady1' value='Yes' checked onClick="PatientReady (this,'111','PatientReady')">
```

you want to use "this" to reference the actual object, if the funciton were using a 'getElementById' function call, then you would be good, but it's not

Answer (score 0):

you have double quote both for delimiting and in your onclick event